# ag-grid header checkbox selected and disable bydefault

Tags: ag-grid

want to selected and disable by default, cant change selection not through headerCheckboxSelection: true,

want to selected and disable by default, cant change selection no change in ag-grid using through angular any version please let me know through any way or method not header selection false method